# wanted to run a python function in background while the main program exits execution

Tags: python, flask

I have a POST method in which accepts user inputs, saves them in db and then send emails as an alert to all the users. While sending the emails it takes too much time and holds the POST method. I wanted to make the send email class to run in background while the POST method completes.

I have little understanding of Process, thread or subprocess, here's what I tried.

```
class SendEmail():
   def __init__(data):
      self.data = data
   def draft_email(self):
      #do something
   def run(self):
      threading.Thread(target=self.draft_email).start()
```

From what I understand this will start a background job however, it will wait for the main to complete which again takes time.
Is there any way I can make this efficient what options I have. I am using Flask framework in Python. Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Comment: it will start another thread, but `.start()` won't block, so execution of the main thread will continue.

Comment: yes, main thread will continue, which can be time consuming, I want the main to finish, while sending emails runs in background

Comment: You can use a thread, if the module you are using to send emails is non-blocking. Otherwise, you will need to use a process.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this [using background tasks with Celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/celery/). Once you complete the setup as explained on the documentation, it is quite simple to use.

For example I use a background task to deploy web apps on the server. This can take up to 2 minutes so it's too long to have an HTTP request depend on it. This is a snippet of my code:

```
@celery.task()
def celery_task_install_app(install_event_id, users_host):
    e = InstallEvents.query.filter_by(id=install_event_id).first()
    e.status = 'initializing'
    db.session.commit()
    cmd = '%s %d' % (app.config['WR_INST_SH'], install_event_id)
    subprocess.run(['ssh', 'root@%s' % users_host, "%s" % cmd])
```

Then I invoke it as follows:

```
@app.route('/users/api/<op>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def users_api(op):
    if _is_admin():
        if op == 'blahblah':
            ...
            ...
        elif op == 'install':
            ...
            celery_task_install_app.delay(new_ie.id, inst_user_host)
            ...
```